# How to pass array in react js inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

I'm developing a IPFS-Ethereum app using React JS where I will upload a XML file and parse it. I got a problem displaying parsed data as an array in the table. It is showing only last element in the array.

```
This is the code used for parsing, in console it is showing the two data in the console which is parsed. But in Table it is showing only the last element. I tried using this this.liItem[i]/this.liItem[0] but it is throwing undefined error.

var request = new Request(`https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`);
fetch(request).then((results) => {
  // results returns XML. lets cast this to a string, then create
  // a new DOM object out of it!
  results
    .text()
    .then((str) => {
      this.state.responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
      console.log(this.state.responseDoc);

      this.state.listItem = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name');
      // console.log(listItem);
      for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.state.listItem.length; this.i++) {
        this.liItem = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name')[this.i].textContent;
        this.setState({
          liItem: this.state.liItem
        });
        console.log(this.liItem);
      }
    })
```

This is the line {this.liItem} used in  in the table to display array data. ([picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFuuc.png))

This is my App.js file.

import {Table, Grid, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import web3 from './web3';
    import ipfs from './ipfs';
    import storehash from './storehash';

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    ipfsHash:null,
    buffer:'',
    ethAddress:'',
    blockNumber:'',
    transactionHash:'',
    gasUsed:'',
    txReceipt: '',
    responseDoc:'',
    listItem:'',
    i:'',
    liItem:[]
  };


  captureFile =(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    let reader = new window.FileReader()
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    reader.onloadend = () => this.convertToBuffer(reader)    
  };

  convertToBuffer = async(reader) => {
    //file is converted to a buffer to prepare for uploading to IPFS
    const buffer = await Buffer.from(reader.result);
    //set this buffer -using es6 syntax
    this.setState({buffer});
  };

  onClick = async () => {
  try{
      this.setState({blockNumber:"waiting.."});
      this.setState({gasUsed:"waiting..."});

      // get Transaction Receipt in console on click
      // See: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3- eth.html#gettransactionreceipt
      await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(this.state.transactionHash, (err, txReceipt)=>{
      console.log(err,txReceipt);
        this.setState({txReceipt});
      }); //await for getTransactionReceipt

      await this.setState({blockNumber: this.state.txReceipt.blockNumber});
      await this.setState({gasUsed: this.state.txReceipt.gasUsed});    
    } //try
    catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    } //catch


    var request = new Request(`https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`);
    fetch(request).then((results) => {
      // results returns XML. lets cast this to a string, then create
      // a new DOM object out of it!
      results
      .text()
      .then(( str ) => {
        this.state.responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
        console.log(this.state.responseDoc);

        this.state.listItem  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name');
                // console.log(listItem);
        for (this.i=0; this.i<this.state.listItem.length; this.i++){
          this.liItem = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name')[this.i].textContent;
          this.setState({liItem: this.state.liItem});
          console.log(this.liItem);
        }
      })
    });
  } //onClick

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //bring in user's metamask account address
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Sending from Metamask account: ' + accounts[0]);

    //obtain contract address from storehash.js
    const ethAddress= await storehash.options.address;
    this.setState({ethAddress});

    //save document to IPFS,return its hash#, and set hash# to state
    //https://github.com/ipfs/interface-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/FILES.md#add 
    await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
      console.log(err,ipfsHash);
      //setState by setting ipfsHash to ipfsHash[0].hash 
      this.setState({ ipfsHash:ipfsHash[0].hash });


      // call Ethereum contract method "sendHash" and .send IPFS hash to etheruem contract 
      //return the transaction hash from the ethereum contract
      //see, this https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

      storehash.methods.sendHash(this.state.ipfsHash).send({
          from: accounts[0] 
        }, (error, transactionHash) => {
          console.log(transactionHash);
          this.setState({transactionHash});
        }

      ); //storehash 
    }) //await ipfs.add
  }; //onSubmit 


  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>
            {" "}
            Ethereum and InterPlanetary File System(IPFS) with Create React App
          </h1>
        </header>
        <hr />

        <Grid>
          <h3> Choose file to send to IPFS </h3>
          <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.captureFile} />
            <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit">
              Send it
            </Button>
          </Form>
          <br />

          <img
            src={`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`}
            alt=""
            style={{ height: 200 }}
          />

          <hr />
          <Button onClick={this.onClick}> Get Transaction Receipt </Button>
          <Table bordered responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Tx Receipt Category</th>
                <th>Values</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>IPFS Hash # stored on Eth Contract</td>
                <td>{this.state.ipfsHash}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ethereum Contract Address</td>
                <td>{this.state.ethAddress}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Tx Hash # </td>
                <td>{this.state.transactionHash}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Block Number # </td>
                <td>{this.state.blockNumber}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gas Used</td>
                <td>{this.state.gasUsed}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>XML</td>
                <td>{this.liItem}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
    //render
  }
}

export default App;
```

I hope you people will understand my question and give me a solution.
Thank You

Comment: Is this how your code appears in your editor? Because proper indentation will go a long way.

Comment: There is no indentation and more than a hundred line of code, how do you want us to answer your question ? Please try to isolate the part of the code that you are struggling with and ensure proper indentation.

Comment: The part of code which i added as I'm getting only last entry is included in the App.js. It looks same as it in the App.js @ChrisG

Comment: I will try to be more clear. Let me edit the code.@ArkDeus

Comment: Please use indentation for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>XML</td>
    <td>{this.liItem.map((value, index) => {
        <p key={index}>{value}</p>
    })}</td>
</tr>
```

with that you should get all the entries in a seperated line (cause p is w=100%)

Comment: if i give this.state.liItem it's not displaying any data in td

Comment: maybe because your state variable is not even added to the this object

Comment: There was little code change now this.state.liItem is working but still getting only last entry displayed in the table @Sandro Schaurer

Comment: i edited my post ... may try it ... should now be more specific. Is it like this ?

Comment: I got the solution why only one entry is showing for me instead of 2. I was not pushing into the array the data when I parsed. So after pushing and using map i got the required output. Thank You @Sandro Schaurer

Comment: can you please mark as 'right answer' if it was helpful ? :) or dont you have enough rep ?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote. Thanks for your help @Sandro Schaurer

Answer (score 1):

There was little change in the code and this worked for me.

```
var request = new Request(`https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`);
  fetch(request).then((results) => {
    // results returns XML. lets cast this to a string, then create
    // a new DOM object out of it!
    //Array Declaration
    var values=[];
    results
      .text()
      .then(( str ) => {
        this.state.responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
        console.log(this.state.responseDoc);

        this.state.listItem  = this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name');
        for (this.i=0; this.i<this.state.listItem.length; this.i++){
        //Pushing values into the array
        values.push(this.state.responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('Name')[this.i].textContent);
        console.log(values);
         }
        this.setState({liItem: values});
      })
    });

 And down in the render I used this for displaying
 <tr>
 <td>
 XML
 </td>
 <td>
 {this.state.liItem.map(x => {return x})}
 </td>
 </tr>
```